# Best way to compute row eigenvectors

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Without qualification, the term eigenvectors (of a matrix) refers to the column eigenvectors (of a matrix) and can be directly computed with `Eigenvectors[]`.  To get the row eigenvectors, one can invert the transpose of the matrix returned by `Eigenvectors[]` (or equivalently, the inverse of `JordanDecomposition[][[1]]`).

This approach is usually fast enough, but sometimes, computing the inverse takes an enormous amount of time, compared to just computing the column eigenvectors.  This can happen when the column eigenvectors are partially symbolic, or involve `Root[]`.

> Is there a better way to compute the row eigenvectors of a matrix?  In particular, is there a way to compute the row eigenvectors as fast as the column eigenvectors?

Comment: Assuming by "row eigenvector" you mean the left eigenvector, you can calculate this by calculating the regular (right) eigenvector of Transpose[a].

Comment: Just compute directly the eigenvectors of the transpose matrix.

Comment: Or compute the SVD, which gives you both the left and right eigenvectors.

Comment: @rm-rf I'm not sure. For example, eigenvectors are not orthogonal for non-Hermitian matrices (Hermitian matrices are out of our scope because they have identical set of left and right eigenvectors) but SVD always returns two orthogonal sets. For definiteness one can calculate eigenvectors and SVD of `{{1, 1}, {0, 2}}`.

Comment: It should be noted that "one can invert the transpose of the matrix returned by `Eigenvectors[]`" will fail if the matrix is defective.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To compute [left eigenvectors](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeftEigenvector.html) ( = "row eigenvectors") you can use

```
Eigenvectors@Transpose[A]
```

See also Daniel's answer [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/KXPmCjPfbqA/9mM9tjwcCHsJ).

Comment: I don't think left eigen vectors is same transpose of right eigenvector. What you are saying is true for matrices which are "Hermitian" matrix.

Comment: @KartikChhajed Please note that `Eigenvectors@Transpose[A]` is `Eigenvectors[Transpose[A]]`, i.e. eigenvectors of the transposed matrix, not the transpose of the right eigenvectors.

Answer (score 8):

Let me provide a wrapper routine for generating the full eigensystem (eigenvalues, and left and right eigenvectors) of a matrix. This uses the *undocumented* built-in LAPACK routines for doing so:

```
SetAttributes[makeVecs, HoldAll];
makeVecs[vals_, vecs_, s_, rQ_] := With[{n = Length[vals]}, 
    If[TrueQ[rQ], 
       Do[Switch[Sign[Im[vals[[k]]]], 0, Null,
                 1, vecs[[k]] += s I vecs[[k + 1]],
                 -1, vecs[[k]] = Conjugate[vecs[[k - 1]]]], {k, n}]]]

Options[getEigensystem] = {Mode -> Automatic};

getEigensystem[mat_?SquareMatrixQ, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
   Module[{m = mat, chk, ei, ev, lm, lv, n, rm, rQ, rv}, n = Length[mat];
          Switch[OptionValue[Mode],
                 Right | Automatic, {lm, rm} = {"N", "V"},
                 Left, {lm, rm} = {"V", "N"},
                 All, {lm, rm} = {"V", "V"},
                 _, {lm, rm} = {"N", "V"}];
          LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`GEEV[lm, rm, m, ev, ei, lv, rv, chk, rQ];
          If[! TrueQ[chk], Message[getEigensystem::eivec0]; Return[$Failed, Module]];
          If[rQ, ev += I ei];
          Switch[OptionValue[Mode],
                 Right | Automatic, rv = ConjugateTranspose[rv];
                                    makeVecs[ev, rv, 1, rQ]; {ev, rv},
                 Left, lv = ConjugateTranspose[lv];
                       makeVecs[ev, lv, -1, rQ]; {ev, lv},
                 All, {lv, rv} = ConjugateTranspose /@ {lv, rv};
                      makeVecs[ev, rv, 1, rQ]; makeVecs[ev, lv, -1, rQ];
                      {ev, rv, lv},
                 _, rv = ConjugateTranspose[rv];
                    makeVecs[ev, rv, 1, rQ]; {ev, rv}]]
```

Test:

```
m = {{1., -2., 1., 9., 6.},
     {8., 5., 3., 7., 7.},
     {-9., -3., 9., 5., -2.},
     {-5., -4., 6., 8., -6.},
     {-3., 9., -2., 6., -3.}};

{vals, rvecs, lvecs} = getEigensystem[m, Mode -> All];

Norm[m.Transpose[rvecs] - Transpose[rvecs].DiagonalMatrix[vals]]
   4.16257*10^-14

Norm[lvecs.m - DiagonalMatrix[vals].lvecs]
   2.73754*10^-14
```

Comment: As a bonus, one can then compute the eigenvalue condition numbers as `MapThread[1/(Normalize[#1].Normalize[#2]) &, {lvecs, rvecs}]`.

Comment: Is there any resource available on the usage of these Lapack functions in Mathematica? Are the function signatures the same as you'd use them in Fortran (In that case one can lookup netlib/lapack)?

Comment: @Galilean, unfortunately, these are *undocumented*, but I've found that their syntax more or less follows the FORTRAN originals, modulo dimension arguments.