# Is it possible to use the DGEEV and DSYEV LAPACK subroutines in Mathematica?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, librarylink, fortran

Here is my problem: I'm diagonalizing some matrices using `Eigensystem[]` to obtain eigenvalues and eigenvectors and I'm diagonalizing the same matrices using a Fortran code that uses DGEEV (DGEEV computes the eigenvalues and right eigenvectors for a real nonsymmetric matrix) or DSYEV (DSYEV computes eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a real symmetric matrix) LAPACK subroutines.

These matrices are of course square but can be real nonsymmetric or symmetric matrices. The problem is that when I compare what I obtain using Mathematica and Fortran I have the same eigenvalues (that are degenerate) but not the same eigenvectors.

So I know that for degenerate eigenvalues Mathematica can give non orthogonal eigenvectors ([found it here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72941/get-eigensystem-to-return-orthogonal-eigenvectors-for-hermitian-matrix)) and I tried stuffs with `Orthogonalize[]` and `Normalize[]` but nothing conclusive yet (I'm still working in this direction).

So I was wondering if any of you know if we can use the DGEEV or DSYEV LAPACK subroutines in Mathematica ?

I have done some research and found some stuffs.

I found the Mathematica equivalent functions to the LAPACK functions as stated by
[Nasser](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/70/nasser%3E) with a table that we can find [here](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/lapack_analysis/lapack.htm).

I also found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100486/how-to-know-the-usage-of-undocumented-function-like-linearalgebrablas) that some (or all ?) BLAS and some LAPACK functions can be used directly in Mathematica by using

```
LinearAlgebra`BLAS`
```

or

```
LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`
```

followed by the name and the right arguments of the function.

I have tried some of these functions without specifying the arguments and Mathematica let me know that I don't have the right number of arguments, here an example:

```
LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`GETRS[];

LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`GETRS::argrx: LinearAlgebra`LAPACK`GETRS called with 0 arguments; 4 arguments are expected.
```

So I tried the same with the DGEEV function (and some other LAPACK functions like the DSYEV subroutine) and Mathematica said nothing.

I also found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/167555/in-what-way-can-m11-3s-system-modelling-features-be-used-by-those-who-dont-hav/167560#167560) something with `SystemModel[]` by using:

```
SystemModel["Modelica.Math.Matrices.LAPACK.dgeev", "ModelicaDisplay"]
```

[image]

But then I don't know if it's possible to use it and if yes, how to use it.

Comment: [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/169578) uses `GEEV`; you might want to study the syntax in that function as a guide on what is retained and omitted compared to the original FORTRAN (e.g. the dimension arguments are typically omitted). `SYEV` should be similar. (See also [this related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100486).)

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I still don't have the same answer than the DGEEV subroutine. But I will continue to look at your answer. Thanks !

Comment: You might want to elaborate when you say you "still don't have the same answer"; otherwise we're all just guessing here.

Comment: I mean I still have different eigenvectors with your proposition and the DGEEV or DSYEV subroutines in Fortran.

Comment: "different eigenvectors" - different, how? Did you account for normalization, or was the usual check identity $\mathbf A\mathbf x=\lambda\mathbf x$ not satisfied for some of the eigenvectors generated?

Answer (score 20):

You can use LibraryLink to call LAPACK directly. It involves however quite a lot of boilerplate code. Here is an example:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
name = "cf";
Quiet[LibraryFunctionUnload[cf]];
ClearAll["cf"]

file = Export[FileNameJoin[{$TemporaryDirectory, name, ".cpp"}],
   "
#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"
#include <cmath>
#include <lapack.h>

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int " <> name <> 
    "(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res)
{
    // Tell the LibraryFunction what the types of its arguments are.

    MTensor A_in            = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
    MTensor lambda_real_out = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[1]);
    MTensor lambda_imag_out = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[2]);
    MTensor V_out           = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[3]);

    // Get the pointers to the buffers of MTensors, so that we can pass them to LAPACK functions.

    mreal * A            = libData->MTensor_getRealData(A_in);
    mreal * lambda_real  = libData->MTensor_getRealData(lambda_real_out);
    mreal * lambda_imag  = libData->MTensor_getRealData(lambda_imag_out);
    mreal * V            = libData->MTensor_getRealData(V_out);

    const int n  = static_cast<int>( libData->MTensor_getDimensions(A_in)[0] );


    // Request the optimal buffer_size for the scratch buffer.

    mreal buffer_dummy = 0.;
    int   buffer_size  = -1;
    int   info = 0;

    dgeev_( \"N\", \"V\", &n, A, &n, lambda_real, lambda_imag, nullptr, &n, V, &n, &buffer_dummy, &buffer_size, &info );

    if( info == 0 )
    {
        buffer_size = round(buffer_dummy);
    
        // Allocate some scratch buffer on which LAPACK can work.

        mreal * buffer = (mreal*)malloc( buffer_size * sizeof(mreal) );
        
        // The actual call to LAPACK.

        dgeev_( \"N\", \"V\", &n, A, &n, lambda_real, lambda_imag, nullptr, &n, V, &n, buffer, &buffer_size, &info );

        // We have to clean up after ourselves...
        free(buffer);
    
    }


    // Make sure that the MTensors passed by reference are _not_ cleaned up by the LibraryFunction.

    libData->MTensor_disown(lambda_real_out); 
    libData->MTensor_disown(lambda_imag_out);
    libData->MTensor_disown(V_out);

    return info;
}"
   ,
   "Text"
   ];
lib = CreateLibrary[{file}, name,
   "ShellOutputFunction" -> Print,
   "CompileOptions" -> {}
   , "LinkerOptions" -> {"-llapack"}
   , "IncludeDirectories" -> {
     "/opt/local/include"    (*I installed LAPACK via macports, so this is the path where to look for the header file.*)
     }
   , "LibraryDirectories" -> {
     "/opt/local/lib"        (*I installed LAPACK via macports, so this is the path where to look for the library file.*)
     }
   ];

cf = LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, name,
  {
   {Real, 2, "Constant"}, (*argument is passed as constant reference*)
   {Real, 1, "Shared"},   (*argument is passed by mutable reference; can be modified.*)
   {Real, 1, "Shared"},   (*argument is passed by mutable reference; can be modified.*)
   {Real, 2, "Shared"}    (*argument is passed by mutable reference; can be modified.*)
  },
  "Void" (*No return value.*)
  ]
```

And here is a basic usage example:

```
n = 4;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];
A = A\[Transpose] . A;

(*Allocate arrays for the return values.*)
\[Lambda]real = ConstantArray[0., n];
\[Lambda]imag = ConstantArray[0., n];
U = ConstantArray[0., {n, n}];

(*Hand A and the arrays for the return values over to the LibraryFunction .*)
cf[A, \[Lambda]real, \[Lambda]imag, U];
(*Return values are now written to \[Lambda]real,\[Lambda]imag and U.*)

{\[Mu], V} = Eigensystem[A];
Max[Abs[A . Transpose[V] - Transpose[V] . DiagonalMatrix[\[Mu]]]];


Max[Abs[Sort[\[Lambda]real] - Sort[\[Mu]]]]
```

> 5.60663*10^-15

That `cf` literally returns the output of `dgeev`. So the outputs might have to be postprocessed, in particular when nonreal eigenvalues are present. See [netlib.org](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d9/d8e/group__double_g_eeigen_ga66e19253344358f5dee1e60502b9e96f.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm not used to headers. I will have a look at it. For the moment I have an error with the #include <lapack.h>. I guess that I have to make a directory with all the headers requested ? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, you to install an appropriate LAPACK distribution ad to make sure that the C++ compiler can find it. Unfortunately, this depends quite heavily on the system that you use.

Comment: Ok I will look at it, thanks. I'm on MacOs BigSur 11.6.2.

Comment: Good, then I can help you. Make sure that XCode is installed and then install Macports. Afterwards, you can execute `sudo port install OpenBLAS` in the command line to install OpenBLAS (which ships a LAPACK implementation). Then the above code should run fine.

Comment: Yes the code runs fine ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: Great! You're welcome!