# How to load a .dylib library (C++ not compile with Mathematica library) on Mac with Mathematica?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, mac-os-x, librarylink, .netlink, c++

I work on a mac M1 with MacOS Sonoma and i use Mathematica 12.3.1 and 14.0

I wanted to ask if there is a way to load a .dylib library on Mac with Mathematica, which was compiled without using the Wolfram library (LibraryFunctionLoad) and without having to compile it with Mathematica (CreateLibrary)?

On Windows, I found that there is something called DefineDLLFunction which seems to work for loading .dll files, but I haven’t been able to make it work with .dylib files on macOS.

I use LibraryFunctionLoad and CreateLibrary already but it force me to put wolfram library in my C++ code and i would want to avoid that if possible

Thanks !

Comment: You merely need to write a wrapper in _LibraryLink_ that calls the function from the external library and makes sure that the results are stored in data types that _Mathematica_ can understand (e.g., in `MTensors`). Then you combile this wrapper with `CreateLibrary` and include the according linker commands with the option `LinkerOptions -> {"-l<library name>}`. You might also have to provide the path to that library with the `LibraryDirectories` and the path to the included header files with the `IncludeDirectories`.

Comment: Does that make sense to you? I could also show a worked out example if you need it.

Comment: Wrap the library and define a C API using `extern "C"` and `__attribute__((visibility("default")))` . You don't necessarily need the Mathematica data types. If the C++ library has a C library interface already you may not have to do this, but otherwise, function names end up mangled in C++. However, even then you could still find those name mangled functions and call those if the signature types are simple ones.

Comment: Here is an example of the practice I mentioned before: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269065/38178

Comment: Ah, okay. So, I can create the wrapper directly from Mathematica. I will try this. I didn’t understand what you said, Flinty: Can I load a C++ library without using a wrapper? Can I do this with LibraryFunctionLoad?

Comment: @Alex, if you ask me: No it is not possible without a wrapper. You have to translate the data types that `Mathematica` uses to something that the library can understand: standard C types and pointers to such.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the example (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/269065/38178)
i succeeded in implementing it like this